# Get SubItem value only from ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

Attempting to get the value of a subitem inside my ListView:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="25" Height="25" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RumNummer}" Margin="12,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Våning}" Margin="150,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

However, I am not exactly sure how to do so. So far I have been successful in getting all the values from the ListView with

```
string txt = listView.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

and I've attempted to look around to figure out how I would only get the value of the "RumNummer" rather than both "RumNummer" and "Våning", so I can store it inside a string.

From what I gather, most people do something similar to this:

```
string txt = listView.SelectItems[0].Subitems[0];
```

but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I think you should be able to get it via *DataContext* of selected item - this will return your class used for items - there you can access your properties directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ListView.SelectedItem will be the item that You are Binding ListView DataTemplate To. For example in this case it will be your class property.

So if Below is a sample of your class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ImagePath {get; set;}
    public string RumNummer {get; set;}
    public string Våning {get; set;}
}
```

Then below is the way you will get the data.

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)listView.SelectedItem
```

Then you can get data as `myclass.RumNummer`